# Rename a data frame that starts with a number in R

Tags: r, renaming

I have a number of data frames in my workspace. Since all had the same pattern I ran a loop to load them. They keep the names that I used for storing them in my computer (in .csv format) The output regarding the names of the data frames look something like this:

```
    [1] "01 July 2015.csv"      "02 September 2015.csv"
    [3] "03 June 2015.csv"      "05 August 2015.csv"   
    [5] ....
```

When I try to rename the data frames (ex. first data frame) I encounter the following error:

> july15 = 01 July.csv
>   Error: unexpected symbol in "july15 = 01 July"

I have not come across a solution for rename data frames that begin with a number and I wonder whether there is a way to handle with this problem. Thanks!

Comment: Try using backticks - `july15 = \`01 July.csv\``

Comment: If you read them into a list rather than your global environment, you can avoid this by referring to them as positions in the list.

Comment: @EduGonzalo: I wish I could use some of my rep to decrease the positive regard expressed for the backtick suggestion. So _wrongity_ _wrong_. Please listen to Thomas.

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions, really appreciated.